# Point wrapping algorithm - A blocked Swinging door

Tags: python

I'm trying to some some code in python. Basically what it does is simulates a door (viewed from above) on an (x,y) coordinate system. The task is given a list of points, determine which the door will hit first, if any.

Determining if a point is within range to be hit by the door is simple enough, determining which point gets hit first is proving to be difficult, as the door can swing clockwise or counter clockwise, and has a rather large, and variable range of swing (in terms of radians/degrees). The issue is mostly that I'm not sure what conditions need to be true for the point to be hit first.

Update:
I do have the angles calculated, but concerned about special cases such as when the door is at 1 degree, and swinging clockwise towards points at angles 180, 190, and 300 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the angle from the door hinge to each of the points; whichever is closest to the current angle of the door itself (hinge to door edge) will be hit first when rotating.

If the cycling is giving you trouble: notice that for any given angle, you can subtract it from 360 to get its complement; whichever is the smaller of the two is the closer way to get to it. So:

1. Calculate all angles for the points a1 ... aN
2. Subtract them all from the door angle to get difference angles d1...dN
3. Replace each dN with min( dN, 360 - dN ) to get the "shorter" approach
4. Pick the minimum

Comment: Indeed, though one of the trouble is dealing with special cases such as angle of 350 degrees and angle of 5 degrees. It becomes even more complicated, when dealing with separate conditions for clockwise and counterclockwise rotating doors.

Comment: Amended my answer, take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it on paper and noticed I was right a long time ago when I was using (dTheta % 360). Seems I made the wrong correction at some point. Wonder if it would be more efficent to min(dN,360-dN) or dN % 360.

Comment: Actually, to be perfectly correct you need both. `dN%360` will give you 355 if the angle difference is -5; and picking the smallest of `min(dN, 360-dN)` only works if all `dN` are positive (which you can get either by doing `dN%360` or `abs(dN)`.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks. Noticed I had issues elsewhere in the code that seem to be causing problems. Don't help much if I'm coding clockwise for counterclockwise doors and vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified if you think in terms of the difference between the angle of door and the angle of each point relative to the hinge of the door.

You then find the angle with this formula:

```
length of vector from hinge to door: A
length of vector from hinge to point: B

angle = (A * B)/(A^2 + B^2)
```

Comment: Really should have added that I already had the angles being calculated. The issue is more along the lines of the cyclic nature of circles. Although the formula might prove useful more useful than using atan2.